# Combine two table with different column but same value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with similar value:

TABLE A

```
a_empno  a_checktime               a_updatetime            a_status  a_location
-------  -----------------------   ----------------------- -------   ---------
1        2016-03-30 07:40:07.000   2016-03-30 07:42:50.843  In        xxxxxxx
2        2016-03-30 07:40:09.000   2016-03-30 07:42:51.543  In        xxxxxxx
3        2016-03-30 18:18:26.000   2016-03-30 19:14:09.673  Out       xxxxxxx
4        2016-03-30 18:18:30.000   2016-03-30 19:14:10.020  Out       xxxxxxx
```

TABLE B

```
b_empno  b_checktime               b_updatetime            b_status  b_location
-------  -----------------------   ----------------------- -------   ---------
1        2016-03-30 07:40:07.000  2016-03-30 08:01:01.000   In        xxxxxxx
2        2016-03-30 18:18:26.000  2016-03-30 21:01:01.370   In        xxxxxxx
```

I'm trying to combine the table so I can get a result where the data in table B will be combined into table A:

```
a_empno  a_checktime               a_updatetime            a_status  a_location
-------  -----------------------   ----------------------- -------   ---------
1        2016-03-30 07:40:07.000   2016-03-30 07:42:50.843  In        xxxxxxx
2        2016-03-30 07:40:09.000   2016-03-30 07:42:51.543  In        xxxxxxx
3        2016-03-30 18:18:26.000   2016-03-30 19:14:09.673  Out       xxxxxxx
4        2016-03-30 18:18:30.000   2016-03-30 19:14:10.020  Out       xxxxxxx
1        2016-03-30 07:40:07.000  2016-03-30 08:01:01.000   In        xxxxxxx
2        2016-03-30 18:18:26.000  2016-03-30 21:01:01.370   In        xxxxxxx
```

Do I have to create another table or is there any other way to do this? I have tried EXISTS and JOIN.

Comment: Have you tried UNION?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a simple `INSERT/SELECT FROM`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (
    a_empno
    ,a_checktime
    ,a_updatetime
    ,a_status
    ,a_location
    )
SELECT b_empno
    ,b_checktime
    ,b_updatetime
    ,b_status
    ,b_location
FROM TABLE_B
```

If your goal is to combine the results from the two tables into *another* table, you should do as [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets) suggests in his comments and use either `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT a_empno
    ,a_checktime
    ,a_updatetime
    ,a_status
    ,a_location
FROM TABLE_A
UNION   --OR UNION ALL IF YOU WANT TO KEEP DUPLICATES
SELECT b_empno
    ,b_checktime
    ,b_updatetime
    ,b_status
    ,b_location
FROM TABLE_B
```